# Reload form after displaying custom message using modal

Tags: forms, ajax

How can I display the form after ajax call and closing the modal? Right now when I use ajax to display the custom message ,but it preserves the state. When I click on modal button it display the same custom message but not the form

My code is as follows:

```
function demo_demo_form($form, &$form_state) {
  return array(
    'email' => array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Join our Newsletter'),
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#attributes' => array(
        'placeholder' => t('mail@example.com'),
      ),
    ),
    'submit' => array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Subscribe'),
      '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'demo_form_ajax_submit',
        'wrapper' => 'demo-demo-form',
        'method' => 'replace',
        'effect' => 'fade',
      ),
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Ajax callback function.
 */
function demo_form_ajax_submit($form, $form_state) {
// Dummy/dumb validation for demo purpose.
  if (!empty($form_state['input']['email'])) {
    $message = "subscription form submitted!";
    return $message;
  }
  else {
    return $form;
  }
}
```

But when I click modal button it shows the same message. I can use `window.location.reload` but I only want to reload the form in the block.

Javascript is as follows:

```
// On Load
(function($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.demo = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $('#mybutton').on( "click", function() {
        $('#block-demo-file-upload').modal('hide');
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

How can I display the form when I open the modal window next time without reloading the page?

Comment: You are not returning `$form` inside `hook_form_submit()`.
`$form` is inside the else so when ever the email value exist it will not return `$form`.

Comment: yes but how to  display the message and when the modal close  render the form?